# Explode string to elements

Tags: php, string, csv, delimiter, explode

I need to `explode()` this

> '194', '??','Dot, is', "3","0", '4', '35',, 0, 'ANIMAL','STUN,SLOW,CURSE,TERROR'

into separated elements.

The content of elements may be in quotation marks or apostrophe (but may not be quoted at all).

Zero-width strings need to be matched as well.

As you can see, I cannot explode it by comma, because commas are included in some elements.

Somewhere there are spaces missing between elements and spaces may be included in element itself.

**Result should be**:

Element 0 = 194
Element 1 = ??
Element 2 = Dot, is
Element 3 = 3
Element 4 = 0
Element 5 = 4
Element 6 = 35
Element 7 =
Element 8 = 0
Element 9 = ANIMAL
Element 10 = STUN,SLOW,CURSE,TERROR

Comment: [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) might be better than explode in this case

Comment: Though do you really have a mixture of single-quote and double-quote enclosures?

Comment: Well, I have made it simpler a lot ... current string is MUCH bigger and yeah, it has sometimes "text" and sometimes 'text' and sometimes just text

Comment: In that case, use [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to convert `'` to `"`; then use [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to convert `'` to `"`; then use [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

```
$str = "'194', '??','Dot, is', \"3\",\"0\", '4', '35',, 0, 'ANIMAL','STUN,SLOW,CURSE,TERROR'";

$array = str_getcsv(
    str_replace("'", '"', $str)
);

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Will this work even for values without any enclosures?

Comment: Enclosures are optional, needed only when the values actually contain the delimiter character, but they do need to be consistent when they are used

Answer (score 0):

Here is the 1 function call / regex way with no capture groups and no string preparation...

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e7aab2f5e1b63b3f86e31c5474b285924a19dda7))  ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/72O38k/1))

```
// Using HEREDOC syntax to avoid escaping quotes in $string and $pattern
$string=<<<EOD
'194', '??','Dot, is', "3","0", '4', '35',, 0, 'ANIMAL','STUN,SLOW,CURSE,TERROR'
EOD;

$pattern=<<<EOD
/(?:^|,)(?: *(?:'\K[^']*|"\K[^"]*|\K[^,]+|\K(?=,)))/
EOD;

var_export(preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$out)?$out[0]:'fail');
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '194',
  1 => '??',
  2 => 'Dot, is',
  3 => '3',
  4 => '0',
  5 => '4',
  6 => '35',
  7 => '',
  8 => '0',
  9 => 'ANIMAL',
  10 => 'STUN,SLOW,CURSE,TERROR',
)
```

There are 4 types of occurrences to match.  I shall list them in the order of my pattern alternatives.

- Single quote wrapped substrings
- Double quote wrapped substrings
- No quote wrapped positive width substrings
- No quote wrapped zero-width substrings

Note: `\K` resets the fullstring match -- this is what permits the omission of capture groups and allows the output array to place all of the matches in a single subarray `[0]`.